# Как избавиться от ошибки role is a required argument that is missing.?

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

```
async def Rainbow(ctx, role : disnake.Role):
    if ctx.message.author.id in acces_id:
        guild = ctx.guild
        role = disnake.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = "Радужный доступ")
        user = ctx.message.author
        await guild.create_role(name="Радужный доступ", colour = disnake.colour(0xff0033))
        await user.add_roles(ctx.message.author, role)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Уходи")
```

Возможно я в глаза дол#люсь, но я не понимаю в чем ошибка,
Гуглил много раз

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых о ошибке.
Она говорит о том, что вы при написании команды `prefix`Rainbow не указываете обязательный аргумент `role` в строке:

```
async def Rainbow(ctx, role : disnake.Role):
```

То есть должно это выглядеть примерно так:
`+Rainbow @role`

Во-вторых зачем вы получаете сначала роль:

```
role = disnake.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = "Радужный доступ")
```

А потом ещё и создаете такую же:

```
await guild.create_role(name="Радужный доступ", colour = disnake.colour(0xff0033))
```

Вы либо взяли код из интернета, либо просто не понимаете о чём пишете.

**Исправьте** свой код, либо попробуйте мою версию:

```
async def Rainbow(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id in #id:
        guild = ctx.guild
        role = disnake.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = "Радужный доступ")
        user = ctx.author
        if role is None:
            role = await guild.create_role(name="Радужный доступ", colour = disnake.colour(0xff0033))
        await user.add_roles(role)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не можете использовать эту команду.")
```